# Showing unique dropdown options in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a following drop down which is working fine

```
                     <select class="form-control" ng-model="cc.id">
                       <option value="">Chose Id</option>
                       <option ng-repeat="account in accounts |unique:'id'" value="{{account.id}}">{{name.id}}</option>
                       </select>
```

It gives me following options in the dropdown

```
          101
          101
          119
          120
          121
          121
```

While it should be only showing the unique id in options as...

```
       101
       119
       120
       121
```

Accounts consists of jason array of Account which has 
act_id (primary key)
id
fname
lname
location

Can you please tell me how to fix the unique filter on id so that it displays only unique values Thanks

Comment: please, provide `accounts` object + name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) has exactly what you need, the ´unique´ filter.

Example:

```
ng-options="color in colors | unique:'name'"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `uniq` method from [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) library.

And just write one row:

```
$scope.new_accounts = _.uniq(accounts, false, function(p){ return p.id; });
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)**</kbd>

*Reference:*

> uniq_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iterator]) Alias: unique 
>   Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iterator function.

```
_.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]);
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381944/ng-options-and-unique-filter-not-displaying-angular-js) AngularJS does not have a unique filter - AngularUI does.

The following code from the link above should help:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});
```

Also, you can use something like this:

```
<select ng-model="accounts" ng-options="c.name for c in accounts"></select><br>
```

for the select.