# AngularJS-Want unique filter to be applied only to dropdown and not to the ng-repeat results

Tags: angularjs

Tried the solution given in [Showing unique dropdown options in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525967/showing-unique-dropdown-options-in-angularjs/21526320#21526320)

```
<select ng-model="categorySelected" ng-options="c.category for c in accounts|unique:'category'">
</select>

<div ng-repeat="c in accounts| filter:categorySelected">
.........
</div>

app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});
```

I also tried

```
<div ng-repeat="c in accounts| filter:{templateCategory: categorySelected}">
```

I have rows fetched from the table and is getting displayed on the html. I want to list unique categories from the result in dropdown. But on selection, i want all the rows belonging to that category to be listed. Now i get the unique categories in the dropdown but even the ng-repeat results show only the unique results which should not be the case. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the use of `filter` in `ngRepeat`.

1) Use `as` to set `categorySelected` to the value of the category selected in the dropdown...

```
<select ng-model="categorySelected" 
    ng-options="a.category as a.category for a in accounts | unique:'category'">
</select>
```

2) User `filter: { category: categorySelected }` in `ngRepeat` to filter accounts by category based on the current value of `categorySelected`...

```
<div ng-repeat="a in accounts | filter : {category: categorySelected}">
    {{ a.name }}
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5JbRK/)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have actually tried what you have shown <div ng-repeat="c in accounts | filter : {category: categorySelected}">
    {{ a.name }}
</div> This gives me no results on changing the dropdown value.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or modify mine to show your problem?

Comment: Hi, I have edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5JbRK/3/  Here it works like a charm. But it is not working in my application, on selecting a dropdown value no results displayed. Has it got to do with libraries? But checkbox works in my application.

Comment: I get the results on load, or on changing the checkbox selection. once i select the dropdown value no results displayed. This has happened after i added filter:{templateCategory: categorySelected} in ng-repeat.

Comment: It is working!! I have no idea why was it not working. May be caching issue. After changing the dropdown values, if i select the default value 'All' i get no results. I will look into that. Thanks for your time

Comment: Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5JbRK/4/ On selecting 'All' i want all the results to be displayed but currently no results displayed. Please help.

Comment: Changed the filter so that if `categorySelected` is "", it'll pass `undefined` to the filter, which makes everything show. Also combined filters into one. See fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/PY7tY/