# AngularJS : How to get the unique values in ng-option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data in a table:

```
data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Manchester United', type: 'Soccer', featured: true, country: 'England'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Manchester City', type: 'Soccer', featured: false, country: 'England'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Dallas Mavericks', type: 'Basketball', featured: true, country: 'USA'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Indian Cricket Team', type: 'Cricket', featured: true, country: 'India'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Australian Cricket Team', type: 'Cricket', featured: false, country: 'Australia'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Los Angeles Lakers', type: 'Basketball', featured: true, country: 'USA'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Los Angeles Clippers', type: 'Basketball', featured: false, country: 'USA'}
];
```

I want to add a drop down box with countries. Selecting a country should filter the table to show only sports from that country.

The problem is that I am unable to show the unique countries in the dropdown.

Kindly Help...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to obtain a list of countries from your data with a plain old JavaScript function, and then just put this function in your controller.

Comment: I am using the following code :
<select data-ng-model="countryModel" ng-options="dd.country for dd in data | unique: data.country">
   <option value="">--Choose Country--</option>
</select>

I was thinking of using a filter (for e.g. 'unique') , how to create a filter is a problem :(

Comment: I was thinking of creating a filter, but unable to do that :(

Comment: Using a filter here is plain wrong. Loop through `data` once and build the list of unique countries.

Comment: This is a bit offtopic, this is a javascript question and not an angular question. Try using from javascript libraries like `lowdash` to preprocess your data.

Comment: @AlexC -- It's both...OP wants an Angular filter applied to his table based off the dropdown - also no need for any more libraries to process the data.

Comment: Looking for the same answer provided here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381944/ng-options-and-unique-filter-not-displaying-angular-js ?

Comment: @allenhwkim I tried using this filter, but it didn't work in my case. It only showed the first country (i.e. England) in the dropdown and nothing else.

Comment: Please look at the plnkr
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YG1OhRGTtHeJI9uikiND?p=info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your plnkr, http://plnkr.co/edit/60GO0zhSGoEUm7tu6mbc?p=preview

Filter: as it is from [ng-options and unique filter not displaying angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381944/ng-options-and-unique-filter-not-displaying-angular-js)

Select part:

`<select data-ng-model="countryModel" ng-options="dd.country as dd.country for dd in data | unique:'country'">`

ng-repeat part

`<tr data-ng-repeat="dat in data | filter: countryModel" data-ng-style="set_color(dat)">`