# How match unique id from template to a filter function in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my **app.js**:

```
.state('app.study_collections', {
    url: "/studies/:studynodeRef",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/overview.html"
      }
    }
})
```

Here is a snippet from my **studies.html**:

```
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="feed-media" ng-repeat="study in studies">
    <img src="{{study.image}}" class="feed-image">
    <div class="feed-gradient-overlay"></div>
    <a href="#/app/studies/{{study.nodeRef}}">
       <h4 class="feed-title">{{study.title}}</h4>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a snippet from my **controller.js**:

```
Studies.all().then(function(payload){
   $scope.studies = payload;
});

Studies.all().then(function(studies){
   $scope.study = $filter('filter')(studies, function (d) {return d.nodeRef === '"'+ $stateParams.studynodeRef + '"';})[0];
});
```

So `Studies.all()` makes call to the studies service which makes asynchronous calls to a json file to get data.

```
Studies.all().then(function(payload){
  $scope.studies = payload;
});
```

This gets the list of all the studies which are iterated in the studies.html file. Each study has its unique nodeRef. When you click on a study it maps to the url `"#/app/studies/{{study.nodeRef}}"`. After that I want to use that nodeRef to filter out a study object from the studies collection which is supposed to be done by

```
Studies.all().then(function(studies){
$scope.study = $filter('filter')(studies, function (d) {return d.nodeRef === '"'+ $stateParams.studynodeRef + '"';})[0];
});
```

where `d.nodeRef === '"'+ $stateParams.studynodeRef + '"'` matches it with the correct nodeRef and filters out that study. But when I try to simply print the study in the template like `{{study}}`, nothing appears and when I do a `console.log()` it is undefined.

How do I fix this? Please let me know if any clarifications are needed.

**Edit**

I made some changes to my controller. I am able to access the nodeRef from the url now but it doesn't work in my filter function for some reason unless I manually enter it. Have a look at it here https://gist.github.com/shubhamsinha92/01b492c62c4dd5ad3a7c

This is what my services.js looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('starter.services', [])


.factory('Studies',function($http,$filter,$q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var studies = [];
    $http.get("studies.json").success(
            function(data){
                //studies = data;
                angular.copy(data, studies);
                //At this point you can filter data as required, or not at all. I would suggest returning the entire JSON response and not filtering here at all, let the controllers filter the data as needed to maintain a layer of separation between controller and service.

                deferred.resolve(studies);
            }
        );

  return {
    all: function(){
      return deferred.promise;
    }
};
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381944/ng-options-and-unique-filter-not-displaying-angular-js

Comment: that's not exactly helpful. I think my problem has something to do with async calls. And If I am missing the point I would really appreciate it if you could demonstrate how to implement it

Comment: I'm pretty unclear on your problem. What are you using the filter for? Why are you calling `Studies.all()` twice?

Comment: one to get all the studies. The second time to filter out a particular study by nodeRef

Comment: Improved the code check it out here: https://gist.github.com/shubhamsinha92/01b492c62c4dd5ad3a7c $scope.study doesn't return anything unless I manually enter the nodeRef

Answer (score 0):

The appears to be that you are comparing '"nodeId"' to 'nodeId'.

Original

```
$filter('filter')(payload, function (d) {
    $scope.id = '"' + $rootScope.nodeId + '"';
    return d.nodeRef === $scope.id ;})[0];
```

Solution

```
$filter('filter')(payload, function (d) {
  $scope.id = "" + $rootScope.nodeId;
  if (d.nodeRef === $scope.id)
    return d;})[0];
```

Please see this example

https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15157/

Comment: Thank you for your response! Are you sure it returns a boolean? Because when I gave d.nodeRef === "some id value" it worked. It just doesn't work for $scope.id for some reason. I tried this again btw:  ` Studies.all().then(function(payload){ $scope.studies = payload;
  $scope.study = $filter('filter')(payload, function (d) {
  $scope.id = '"' + $rootScope.nodeId + '"';
  if (d.nodeRef === $scope.id)
    return d;})[0]; 
});` I can access {{id}} on my template but still don't get anything for {{study}}

Comment: Ok I believe the issue was the comparison.  Please can you try something like $scope.id =  "" + $rootScope.nodeId;  I have updated the JSFiddle