# Populate new Array on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

`$scope` an array consisting Code and Amount on controller. When calculating summary on a function, browser gets Uncaught `Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` error which caused from infinite loop (Strange but it is working).

Is there any proper way to combine new Array while `ng-repeat` without getting infinite loop errors?

Any help would be appreciated

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20008/)

Update: Lines variables are not static, can be added, modified or removed.
[jsFiddle Line for Update](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20010/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Lines = [ {Code:'X', Amount:'10'},
                       {Code:'Y', Amount:'10'}, 
                       {Code:'Z', Amount:'20'},
                       {Code:'Y', Amount:'1'}];

    $scope.Sums =  function(){
        var sums = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Lines.length; i++) {
            var added = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < sums.length; j++) {
                if (sums[j].Code == $scope.Lines[i].Code) {
                    sums[j].Amount = parseFloat( sums[j].Amount) + parseFloat($scope.Lines[i].Amount);
                    added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!added) {
                sums.push( { Code:$scope.Lines[i].Code,  Amount: $scope.Lines[i].Amount  } );
            }
        }
        return sums;
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table style="border:  1px solid black;">
      <tr ng-repeat="line in Lines">
         <td>{{ line.Code }}</td>
         <td>{{ line.Amount }}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   Summary 
   <table style="border:  1px solid black;">
      <tr ng-repeat="sum in Sums()">
         <td>{{ sum.Code }}</td>
         <td>{{ sum.Amount }}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andre Kreienbring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33780903/360067) pointed out the problem is because your `sum()` is returning an object.

I would suggest using filters to accomplish what you need, like so

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table style="border:  1px solid black;">
      <tr ng-repeat="line in Lines">
           <td>{{ line.Code }}</td>
           <td>{{ line.Amount }}</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    Summary 
      <table style="border:  1px solid black;">
      <tr ng-repeat="sum in Lines | unique : 'Code'">
           <td>{{ sum.Code }}</td>
           <td>{{ Lines | filter: { Code: sum.Code } : true | sum: 'Amount' }}</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Lines = [ {Code:'X', Amount:'10'},{Code:'Y', Amount:'10'}, 
                    {Code:'Z', Amount:'20'},{Code:'Y', Amount:'1'}];
}


myApp.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});

myApp.filter('sum', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            sum += Number(input[i][key]);
        }
        return sum;
    };
});
```

The unique filter is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382680/360067

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/34od99sz/

Answer (score 2):

Does this still happen if you do this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.Lines = [ {Code:'X', Amount:'10'},{Code:'Y', Amount:'10'}, 
                    {Code:'Z', Amount:'20'},{Code:'Y', Amount:'1'}];

    $scope.Sums = [];
    calculate();

    var calculate =  function(){

        $scope.Sums.length = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Lines.length; i++) {

              var added = false;
              for (var j = 0; j < $scope.Sums.length; j++) {

                  if ($scope.Sums[j].Code == $scope.Lines[i].Code) {
                      $scope.Sums[j].Amount = parseFloat( $scope.Sums[j].Amount) + parseFloat($scope.Lines[i].Amount);
                      added = true;
                      break;
                  }

              }

              if (!added) {
                  $scope.Sums.push( { Code:$scope.Lines[i].Code,  Amount: $scope.Lines[i].Amount  } );

              }

          }
    }
}
```

Note that it is important to never create a new array once Sums is watched by angular. Use `$scope.Sums.length = 0` instead if you need to empty it.

In your view: `<tr ng-repeat="sum in Sums">`

Comment: Thanks but it is not feasible because Lines are adding, removing or editing on view.  I have to inject calculate(); function to anywhere that modifies Lines array or Lines members.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather put a `$watch` on `$scope.Lines` which will create an array and populate it as `$scope.sums` such that ng-repeat doesn't have to call the method again and again. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p35a8akf/)

**Edit (added missing parameter for deep watching):**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qdzwqrL/)

Comment: Thats my fault on simplifying question It is not working when you update Amount http://jsfiddle.net/p35a8akf/1/

Comment: My mistake: The parameter for deep watching was missing. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qdzwqrL/)

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistaken in the line

```
for (var j = 0; j < sums.length; j++)
```

you try to take the length of sums whitch is a new array. it has no length though. Also why do you use

```
 var sums = new Array();
```

to initialize the array and not

```
var sums = [];
```