# Angular JS multiple select box filter not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning angularjs and was struggling with selection as well. I know this question is already answered but wanted to share some more code nevertheless.

In my test I have two listboxes: tournament name and tournament city

tournament city should be unique

When i select tournament name it  will show up corresponding tournament name list it coming correct only
When i seclect city in selectbox it wont populate any thing

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.tournaments = [
     { id: 1, name: 'Banglore Cup', city:'Banglore' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Banglore Cup1', city:'Mumbai' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Banglore Cup2', city:'Banglore' },
     { id: 4, name: 'Mumbai Cup1', city:'Mumbai' },
     { id: 5, name: 'Mumbai Cup2', city:'Banglore' }
   ];
});



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s4 input-field ">
                <select class="browser-default"  name="show-filter" ng-model="tournamentFilter.id" ng-options="eachTournament.id as eachTournament.name for eachTournament in tournaments">
                    <option value="" selected> All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 input-field ">
                <select class="browser-default" name="show-filter" ng-model="tournamentFilter.city" ng-options="eachTournament.city as eachTournament.city for eachTournament in tournaments| unique:'city'">
                    <option value="" selected> All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12">
        <table class="list_tournament">
            <tbody ng-repeat="eachTournament in tournaments | filter:{id:tournamentFilter.id||undefined} | orderBy:'name'">
                <tr class="row nomargin">
                    <td class="col s4 m3 tournament_list_location">
                        <a href="#/viewtournament/{{eachTournament.id}}">{{eachTournament.name}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tournament_list_location col s12 m3">
                        {{eachTournament.city}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Can you help me to getting data

Comment: please add a fiddle or plunker

Comment: @cherry http://plnkr.co/edit/I4iCnEoRBDF8OWaX9vry?p=preview

Comment: @SaEChowdary thankyou i actually i dont know how to create fiddle or plnkr.please help me my question

Comment: See the above plunk @Aravi

Comment: @SaEChowdary yea i seen but entire city list is not populated why?.Can you undestand my use case.Both should be individual.Each tournament have only one city.But same city have multiple tournaments

Comment: @SaEChowdary Actually the problem is i added Tournament name filter in ng-repeat for displaying but  how can i add city filter in ng-repeat

Comment: Do you want to add filter to name and to city in your ng-repeat?

Comment: @ElmerDantas yes Sir both select box should be individual

Comment: I see now that `angularJS` doesn't provide `unique` filter, `AngularUI` does. You can look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381944/ng-options-and-unique-filter-not-displaying-angular-js) - that has the same answer provided below -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom filter from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381944/ng-options-and-unique-filter-not-displaying-angular-js) to get only unique values : [**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dudtjv4W5FBh8sTi8KeK?p=preview)

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});
```

**Html:** 
Change the filter like below :

```
<tbody ng-repeat="eachTournament in tournaments | filter:{id:tournamentFilter.id, city: tournamentFilter.city||undefined} | orderBy:'name'">
```

Comment: but initially when i select city nothing happen

Comment: City is getting selected right ? What is your expectation in that situation ?

Comment: the problem is when i click any one city or name then after select all it wont populate understand checkit your plunker

Comment: Nice work suzo you help me alot thank you please correct your plunker tournament name select is closed before optioning ok....Thank you verymuch